# Windows Universal - Media Element - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, win-universal-app, mediaelement

I have been playing around with Windows Universal Apps and have ran into a problem were i cant get a video file to play.

```
    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim FILM As String = "C:\Users\User\Documents\Movies\A Movie.Mp4"
    mediaElement.Source = New Uri(FILM, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    mediaElement.Play()
End Sub
```

I have had a look online and cant seem to find a clear enough answer for VB.

When the program start it doesnt display any error.

Also when i tried this in a windows WPF it works fine as long as have this

```
mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual
```

However this option isn't available in Windows Universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't access directly to the files like WPF or Silverlight . UWP apps have some restrictions.

You need to use a Filepicker o get the stream of the media file that you want to play 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

after that you need to set the stream in your media element using SetSource property

please check the documentation all the examples are for c# but they are very simple and easy to translate to vb.net

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187272.aspx

Comment: Cheers mate, funny enough i tried it using the FilePicker and got it to work about an hour after i posted this question, thanks agian.

Comment: perfect!! Please mark this answer if it's was useful for you! :)